# Laravel API call from Vue.js cause CORS for GET routes

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, axios

I recently wanted to integrate the VueJS front end app to my Laravel application. First of all, I installed `fruitcake/laravel-cors` library in `Laravel` and made the connection from `Vue.js` to Laravel using `Vue Axios`. Now all types of requests working (`POST`, `PUT`, `UPDATE`...) except `GET`. Specifications are as follow:

Laravel App:

- Middleware:

  ```
  protected $middleware = [
     //... Rest of the middleware
     //CORS middleware
     \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class 
  ];
  ```
- CORS Config file:

  ```
  return [

      /*
       * You can enable CORS for 1 or multiple paths.
       * Example: ['api/*']
       */
      'paths' => ['api/*'],

      /*
      * Matches the request method. `[*]` allows all methods.
      */
      'allowed_methods' => ['POST', 'GET', 'OPTIONS', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE'],

      /*
       * Matches the request origin. `[*]` allows all origins.
       */
      'allowed_origins' => explode(' ', env('API_ALLOWED_ORIGINS')),

      /*
       * Matches the request origin with, similar to `Request::is()`
       */
      'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

      /*
       * Sets the Access-Control-Allow-Headers response header. `[*]` allows all headers.
       */
      'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

      /*
       * Sets the Access-Control-Expose-Headers response header with these headers.
       */
      'exposed_headers' => [],

      /*
       * Sets the Access-Control-Max-Age response header when > 0.
       */
      'max_age' => 0,

      /*
       * Sets the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header.
       */
      'supports_credentials' => false,
  ];
  ```
- ENV file

  ```
  API_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=http://localhost:8080
  ```
- Route:

  ```
  Route::get('/something', 'SomeComtroller@someAction');
  ```

Vue.JS App:

- Axios get method:

  ```
  get(resource, slug = "") {
      return Vue.axios.get(`${resource}/${slug}`).catch(error => {
        // console.log(error);
        throw new Error(`ApiService ${error}`);
      });
  },
  ```
- API Call

  ```
  ApiService.get("something")
    .then(({ data }) => {
       console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(({ response }) => {
       console.log(response.data);
     });
  ```

Browser Output:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://laravel.app/api/something' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
```

The same route with `POST` is working, but now working with `GET`.

**Update**

Developer Console Network Tab:

```
    HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
    Date: Fri, 10 Apr 2020 16:54:26 GMT
    Server: Apache
    Location: http://laravel.app/api/something
    Content-Length: 244
    Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
    X-Pad: avoid browser bug
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with trailing slash generated by the following function:

```
get(resource, slug = "") {
  return Vue.axios.get(`${resource}/${slug}`).catch(error => {
    // console.log(error);
    throw new Error(`ApiService ${error}`);
  });
},
```

When the `slug` is not passed then the function request data through API with trailing slash, so removed the `slug` parameter from function and API call and the problem is solved.

```
get(resource) {
  return Vue.axios.get(`${resource}`).catch(error => {
    // console.log(error);
    throw new Error(`ApiService ${error}`);
  });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with an update on this line

```
'allowed_origins' => explode(' ', env('API_ALLOWED_ORIGINS', 'http://localhost:8080')),
```

Or also try with clear the cache, config value. and restart the server and the application.

Comment: No result for doing above. I posted my own answer.