# laravel post method is not working.Althought GET method is working

Tags: laravel

My POST method is not  working in whole project only GET is working.I have added csrf filed,cleaned all cache,I did composer dump n much more.but still POST is not working
I am sharing my route and code:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'Blog', 'as' => 'Blog.','namespace'=>'admin\blog'], function () {
    Route::get('view', ['as' => 'view', 'uses' => 'BlogController@view']);
    Route::get('add', ['as' => 'add', 'uses' => 'BlogController@add_view']);
    Route::post('add_blog', ['as' => 'add_blog', 'uses' => 'BlogController@add']);
    Route::get('update_view/{id}', ['as' => 'update_view', 'uses' => 'BlogController@update_view']);
    Route::post('update{id}', ['as' => 'update', 'uses' => 'BlogController@update']);
    Route::get('delete/{id}', ['as' => 'delete', 'uses' => 'BlogController@delete']);
});

<form action="{{ route('Blog.update,[$id]') }}" method="post" class="text-center" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<input type = "text"  id="id" name="id" value="{{ $id }}">
<input type = "text" value="{{ $data[0]->title }}">
<button type = "submit" >Update</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Check author or my answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61144313/laravel-api-call-from-vue-js-cause-cors-for-get-routes/61144948

Comment: add $request result that sent to your controller into your question

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a slash within your update route

Comment: Does the route get hit at all? What error are you getting?

Comment: get route are working .....This error I am facing today only........before that my post and get was working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this edit helps you:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'Blog', 'as' => 'Blog.','namespace'=>'admin\blog'], function () {
    Route::get('view', ['as' => 'view', 'uses' => 'BlogController@view']);
    Route::get('add', ['as' => 'add', 'uses' => 'BlogController@add_view']);
    Route::post('add_blog', ['as' => 'add_blog', 'uses' => 'BlogController@add']);
    Route::get('update_view/{id}', ['as' => 'update_view', 'uses' => 'BlogController@update_view']);
    Route::post('update/{id}', ['as' => 'update', 'uses' => 'BlogController@update']);
    Route::get('delete/{id}', ['as' => 'delete', 'uses' => 'BlogController@delete']);
});

<form action="/update/{{ $id }}" method = "post" class="text-center" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
<input type = "text"  id="id" name="id" value="{{ $id }}">
<input type = "text" value="{{ $data[0]->title }}">
<button type = "submit" >Update</button>
</form>
```

Comment: No this working.....It might be issue of route group in Laravel....Because post method of all route groups are not working...only GET is wokring